# WPF ListBox SelectedItems determine Ctrl or Shift pressed for selection

Tags: wpf, listbox

I need to know, if the SelectedItems got filled when Ctrl or Shift was pressed or not. Is there an easy way (without creating a new controltemplate) to get this info? I prefer solutions without code behind.

Best regards
Yannik

Comment: Why do you need this information? Just set the SelectionMode to MultiExtended and your SelectedItems will be filled.

Comment: I need to collect selected items from various child view models, and in the master view model I want to act upon the selection of all child view models. If only one item is selected (over all child view models), I act different than when multibple items are selected. The selections in the child view models are bound to a custom ObservableCollection which is bound to SelectedItems of ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with minimal code behind.

The main concept is, that I attach to KeyDown and KeyUp events in the MainWindow and set a property "CurrentKeyboardKeyPressed" on the MainViewModel, which propagates the pressed key info to the child view models, which in turn fire a custom event with a special Selection class that has the currently pressed key info.

The posted source code is heavyli shortened and does not run at all. If somebody is interested in the working solution, just ask me and I will email it.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowViewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = _mainWindowViewModel;
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl)
        {
            _mainWindowViewModel.CurrentKeyboardKeyPressed = PressedKeyboardKey.Ctrl;
            return;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift)
        {
            _mainWindowViewModel.CurrentKeyboardKeyPressed = PressedKeyboardKey.Shift;
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainWindowViewModel.CurrentKeyboardKeyPressed = PressedKeyboardKey.None;
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // child view models
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TTSViewModel> _ttsViewModels;

    private PressedKeyboardKey _currentKeyboardKeyPressed;

    public EventHandler<KeyboardKeyPressedEventArgs> CurrentKeyboardKeyPressedChanged;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _ttsViewModels = new ObservableCollection<TTSViewModel>();
    }

    public PressedKeyboardKey CurrentKeyboardKeyPressed
    {
        get { return _currentKeyboardKeyPressed; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentKeyboardKeyPressed != value)
            {
                _currentKeyboardKeyPressed = value;
                OnCurrentKeyboardKeyPressedChanged(_currentKeyboardKeyPressed);
            }
        }
    }

    // create child view models
    public void PopulateTTSList(int itemsToCreated)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsToCreated; i++)
        {
            var tts = new TTSViewModel("TTS " + i);

            tts.FractionSelectionChanged += OnTTSFractionSelectionChanged;
            CurrentKeyboardKeyPressedChanged += tts.CurrentKeyboardKeyPressedChanged;
            _ttsViewModels.Add(tts);
        }
    }

    private void OnCurrentKeyboardKeyPressedChanged(PressedKeyboardKey currentKeyboardKeyPressed)
    {
        var handler = CurrentKeyboardKeyPressedChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new KeyboardKeyPressedEventArgs(currentKeyboardKeyPressed));
        }
    }

    // selection changed handler for each child view model
    private void OnTTSFractionSelectionChanged(object sender, ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs fractionSelectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var sendingTTS = sender as TTSViewModel;
        if (fractionSelectionChangedEventArgs.Selection.PressedKeyOnSelection == PressedKeyboardKey.None)
        {
            // single selection action goes here
            // ....
        }
        else
        {
            // multi selection action goes here
            // ....
        }
    }
}
```

TTSViewModel.cs (child view model)

```
public class TTSViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly SmartObservableCollection<FractionViewModel> _currentlySelectedfractions;
    public EventHandler<ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs> FractionSelectionChanged;
    private PressedKeyboardKey _currentKeyboardKeyPressed;

    public TTSViewModel()
    {
        _currentlySelectedfractions = new SmartObservableCollection<FractionViewModel>();
        _currentlySelectedfractions.CollectionChanged += CurrentlySelectedfractionsOnCollectionChanged;
    }

    public void CurrentKeyboardKeyPressedChanged(object sender, KeyboardKeyPressedEventArgs currentKeyboardKeyPressedEventArgs)
    {
        _currentKeyboardKeyPressed = currentKeyboardKeyPressedEventArgs.CurrentKeyboardKeyPressed;
    }

    private void CurrentlySelectedfractionsOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (FractionSelectionChanged != null)
        {
            if (notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace && notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems != null)
            {
                var removed = _oldSelectedfractions.Except(_currentlySelectedfractions);
                var added = _currentlySelectedfractions.Except(_oldSelectedfractions);

                var selection = new Selection<FractionViewModel>(added, removed, _currentKeyboardKeyPressed);

                _oldSelectedfractions.Clear();
                foreach (var currentlySelectedfraction in _currentlySelectedfractions)
                {
                    _oldSelectedfractions.Add(currentlySelectedfraction);
                }

                var selectionChangedArgs = new ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs(selection);
                FractionSelectionChanged(this, selectionChangedArgs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Selection.cs

```
public sealed class Selection<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _added;
    private readonly List<T> _removed;
    private readonly PressedKeyboardKey _currentKeyboardKeyPressed;

    public Selection()
    {
        _added = new List<T>();
        _removed = new List<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Selection{T}" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="addedItems">[NotNull]</param>
    /// <param name="removedItems">[NotNull]</param>
    /// <param name="currentKeyboardKeyPressed">The current keyboard key pressed.</param>
    public Selection(IEnumerable<T> addedItems, IEnumerable<T> removedItems, PressedKeyboardKey currentKeyboardKeyPressed)
    : this()
    {
        _added.AddRange(addedItems);
        _removed.AddRange(removedItems);
        _currentKeyboardKeyPressed = currentKeyboardKeyPressed;
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<T> Added
    {
        get { return _added; }
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<T> Removed
    {
        get { return _removed; }
    }

    public PressedKeyboardKey PressedKeyOnSelection
    {
        get { return _currentKeyboardKeyPressed; }
    }
}
```

KeyboardKeyPressedEventArgs.cs

```
public sealed class KeyboardKeyPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public KeyboardKeyPressedEventArgs(PressedKeyboardKey currentKeyboardKeyPressed)
    {
        CurrentKeyboardKeyPressed = currentKeyboardKeyPressed;
    }

    public PressedKeyboardKey CurrentKeyboardKeyPressed { get; private set;     }
}
```

ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs.cs

```
public sealed class ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs(Selection<FractionViewModel> newSelection)
    {
        Selection = newSelection;
    }

    public Selection<FractionViewModel> Selection { get; private set; }
}
```

PressedKeyboardKey.cs

```
public enum PressedKeyboardKey
{
    None,
    Ctrl,
    Shift
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wire up selection changed event, and check if Modifier Keys are pressed for Selection.

```
    void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var isCtrlorShiftDown = (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift));
        if (isCtrlorShiftDown)
        {
            // Write your Logic Here;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly the code-behind that I don't want to use:-)